# How can i get sender message from dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am using `dialogflow-fulfillment` library. I found out that different platform has different agent response. Currently I am retrieving the sender message separated by each platform. But this means that I have to write message retrieval logic for each platform. Is there a common way to retrieve sender message instead?

I am expecting some built in function like `agent.get('senderMessage')`

```
function welcome(agent) {
   let senderMessage = '';

   if (agent.originalRequest.source === 'telegram') {
      senderMessage = agent.originalRequest.payload.data.text
   } else if (agent.originalRequest.source === 'facebook') {
      senderMessage = agent.originalRequest.payload.data.message.text
   }
}
```

Telegram

```
{
  source: 'telegram',
  payload: {
    data: {
      text: 'hello',
      date: 123
      from: [Object],
      chat: [Object],
      message_id: 76
    }
  }
}
```

**Facebook**

```
{
  source: 'facebook',
  payload: {
    data: {
      recipient: [Object],
      message: {
         text: 'hello',
      },
      timestamp: 123
      sender: [Object]
    },
    source: 'facebook'
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try using the package 'dialogflow-fulfillment-utils' and use the function getMessages()    https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow-fulfillment-utils